# Como configurar correctamente la paginacion en jquery DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables, asp

Vengo solicitando ayuda para resolver un problema de paginación con jquery DataTables...

Soy nuevo utilizando Jquery DataTables y estoy queriendo hacer una paginacion. Estoy haciendo una vista usando ASP.NET 6, bootstrap y DataTables. El problema es que no me cargan los estilos de los botones de paginado, ¿por qué podría ser eso?

Adjunto el codigo que estoy utilizando:

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">


<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   
    <table id="my-data-table" class="table table-striped table-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Número Turno
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Fecha Registro
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Nombre Compleo
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Dui
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Sucursal
                </th>
                <th class="text-md-right">
                    Login
                </th>
                @*<th class="text-md-right">
                    Estado Turno
                </th>*@

            </tr>
        </thead>
        @if (ViewData["Datos"] != null)
        {
            
        
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ViewData["Datos"] as IList<AppTomaTurnoBarberia.Models.MBarberia>)
            {
                <tr role="row">
                    @*<td> </td>*@
                    <td>
                        @item.NumeroTurno
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-md-right">
                        @item.FechaRegistro
                    </td>

                    <td class="text-md-right">
                        @item.NombreComp
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-md-right">
                        @item.Dui
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-md-right">
                        @item.NombreSucursal
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Login
                    </td>
                    @*<td>
                        @item.EstadoTurno
                    </td>*@
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
        }
    </table>

</div>
```

Layout Css:

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<!--  extension responsive  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
```

Layout Js:

```html
 <!-- extension normal -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!-- extension responsive -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

Js:

```html
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#my-data-table').DataTable({
                //"dom": '<"row justify-content-between top-information"lf>rt<"row justify-content-between bottom-information"ip><"clear">'
            responsive: true,
            bPaginate: true,
            searching: true,
            bFilter: true,
            bInfo: true,
            ordering: false,
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            "bJQueryUI": true,

            language: {
                "decimal": ",",
                "thousands": ".",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                //'bPaginate': true,
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "Primero",
                    "sLast": "Último",
                    "sNext": "Siguiente ",
                    "sPrevious": " Anterior"
                },
                "sProcessing": "Cargando..."
            }
            });

        
        
        });

    </script>
```

}

Adjunto una imagen de como se ve actualmente la vista y los botones de paginado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias...

Comment: No se porque no me cargo la imagen, pero basicamente no se muestran los estilos de los botones, unicamente el enlace... osea (Previous 123456.. Next)

Comment: La imagen no la incluyó porque borraste la referencia a la misma, que el editor pone al pie de página. Algo como `[1]: https://link/a/la/imagen`.  (el número entre los corchetes puede variar) Como no creo que lo hayas guardado, sugiero que edites la pregunta y la agregues de nuevo, teniendo el cuidado de no eliminar dicha referencia.

Comment: Sinceramente no se como se hace para editarla, creo que debo tener ese privilegio, pero yo no lo tengo

Comment: Todos pueden [edit] sus propias publicaciones. No se requiere privilegios especiales para eso. Solo dale clic donde dice _Editar_ (en este comentario o al pie de la pregunta). Te invito a re-visitar el [tour], que explica el funcionamiento en general de StackOverflow.

Comment: Gracias la verdad nunca habia editado una pregunta, pero ya añadi la imagen, gracias